# Payflow Gateway w/ Secure Token & Transparent Redirect - return URL issue

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro, payflowlink

I've built a client (in .NET, but it could be in any framework) to consume the Payflow Gateway NVP API using the Transparent Redirect and Secure Token features. I am able to receive the token, send the credit card data, and receive an Approved response from PayPal. The problem is that PayPal is not redirecting properly back to my site. I passed a RETURNURL (http://localhost:49881/transaction/details?processor=PayflowGateway) parameter when requesting the Secure Token, but instead of returning me to that URL after the transaction, it navigates my browser to the following URL:

> https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49881%2Ftransaction%2Fdetails%3Fprocessor%3DPayflowGateway?POSTFPSMSG=No%20Rules%20Triggered&RESPMSG=Approved&ACCT=1111&COUNTRY=US&PROCCVV2=M&VISACARDLEVEL=12&CVV2MATCH=Y&CARDTYPE=0&PNREF=A70A8EB8B6A1&AVSDATA=XXN&SECURETOKEN=9eGKZsSldEU6mIdSEV5DB4wWd&PREFPSMSG=No%20Rules%20Triggered&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=US&AMT=14.75&SECURETOKENID=1850a8f2-f180-4474-aa31-35d736fd7921&TRANSTIME=2016-03-24%2007:58:48&HOSTCODE=A&COUNTRYTOSHIP=US&RESULT=0&BILLTOCOUNTRY=US&AUTHCODE=872PNI&EXPDATE=1218

I have tried removing the "?processor=PayflowGateway" to fix the multiple question mark issue in the URL, but that doesn't seem to help. I've also tried tagging the RETURNURL[xx] with xx being the length of the URL value, but that seems to be the same as not passing a RETURNURL at all as it just shows a confirmation page on paypal.com instead of redirecting back to my site.

In PayPal Manager, I set the "Show confirmation page" setting to "On my website", Return URL to blank, and Return URL Method to GET. Are there any other settings or API request changes I need to make to get this to return properly to my test site?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because you're URL-Encoding the RETURNURL parameter passed when requesting the secure token from payflowpro gateway.

See the **Do Not URL Encode Name-Value Parameter Data** section on the [Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/).

Also, [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ccpayflow/code.php) you can get some C# code working you can use.

And some guidelines about PayPal HTTP [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1348&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en).

Do not use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` nor `System.Net.WebClient` to make the HTTP POST to request the secure token. Instead use the low level `System.Net.WebRequest` to be able to write the POST data unencoded.

For example:

```
private string RequestSecureToken(double amount)
{
    var secureTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"PARTNER", "PayPal"},
        {"VENDOR", "VENDOR NAME"},
        {"USER", "USER NAME"},
        {"PWD", "PASSWORD"},
        {"TRXTYPE", "S"},
        {"AMT", amount.ToString()},
        {"CREATESECURETOKEN", "Y"},
        {"SECURETOKENID", secureTokenId},
        {"SILENTTRAN", "TRUE"},
        {"RETURNURL", "http://mycompany.com/success"},
        {"ERRORURL", "http://mycompany.com/error"}
    };
    string postData = string.Join("&", pairs.Select(p => string.Format("{0}[{2}]={1}", p.Key, p.Value, p.Value.Length)));
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/namevalue";
    request.Headers.Add("X-VPS-CLIENT-TIMEOUT", "45");
    request.Headers.Add("X-VPS-REQUEST-ID", requestId);
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(postData);
    }
    //Get the response
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```